# How to rewrite function for react React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I know about the new rules. But I still don't understand. Please help me rewrite the code so that there is no error 'Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. '

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import CartPage from "./CartPage/CartPage";
import ProductList from "./Products/ProducList";
const Main = ({ cartDataProops }) => {
  return (
    <main className="main">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-3">Filter</div>
          <div className="col-lg-9">
            <Routes>
              <Route
                path="/"
                exact
                render={() => (
                  <ProductList cartDataProopsTwo={cartDataProops} />
                )}
              />

              <Route path="/cart" component={CartPage} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: PLease provide more details. When does this error appears? Can you also post the full stack trace? What version of react-router-dom are you using?

Comment: @IgorGonak Use the last one version.  I have one element 
```
<ProductList cartDataProopsTwo={cartDataProops} />
```
And then i  made this 
```
 <Routes>
              <Route
                path="/"
                exact
                render={() => (
                  <ProductList cartDataProopsTwo={cartDataProops} />
                )}
              />

              <Route path="/cart" component={CartPage} />
            </Routes>
```

Comment: Just FYI, there are *completely optional* actions you can take after [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help indicate the helpfulness/usefulness of any answers. Welcome to SO. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not rendering any routed components on any of the routes. The error is only pointing out the issue with the current route being rendered, i.e. `"/"`,  that there is no content being rendered. In `react-router-dom@6` all the `Route` components render their content on a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. There are no longer any `component` or `render` and `children` function props.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={<ProductList cartDataProopsTwo={cartDataProops} />}
  />
  <Route path="/cart" element={<CartPage />} />
</Routes>
```